# JQuery - remove added class on body click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check below snippet or this [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/ken445p2/). I wanted to achieve two things from below snippet, that is

1. Add `.myBackground` class while clicking on `.myDiv`
2. Remove `.myBackground` when clicking somewhere else on `body`.

When am trying them separately they are working absolutely fine. But when I try to achieve both of them together not working as expected. I know both click events get fired when clicking on my div, that is why `.myBackground` not getting added. Is there any other way to achieve my requirement?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.myDiv', function() {
    $(this).addClass('myBackground');
  });
  $(document).on('click', 'body', function() {
    $('.myDiv.myBackground').removeClass('myBackground');
  })
});
```

```css
.myDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: cyan;
}

.myBackground {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv">
</div>
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the element in your body so when you click it registers both clicks ,use a if to trigger the remove only if the element is not the .myBackground/myDiv element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.myDiv', function() {
    $(this).addClass('myBackground');
  });
  $(document).on('click', 'body', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.myBackground'))
      $('.myBackground').removeClass('myBackground');
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.myDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: cyan;
}

.myBackground {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="myDiv">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop event from propagating-up till body level by adding

```
e.stopPropagation()
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.myDiv', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('myBackground');
    e.stopPropagation()
  });
  $(document).on('click', 'body', function() {
    $('.myDiv.myBackground').removeClass('myBackground');
  })
});
```

```css
body
{
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.myDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: cyan;
}

.myBackground {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="myDiv">
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add e.stopProgation(); 
[some more info about it](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```js
var addBackground = function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.myDiv').addClass('myBackground');
};

var removeBackground = function(){
    $('.myDiv.myBackground').removeClass('myBackground');
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myDiv').on('click',addBackground);
  $('body').on('click',removeBackground);
});
```

```css
.myDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: cyan;
}

.myBackground {
  background: red;
}

body
{
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="myDiv">
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){

 $(document).on('click', 'body', function(e) {
     if ($(e.target).hasClass('myBackground'))
         $('.myDiv').removeClass('myBackground');
     else if ($(e.target).hasClass('myDiv'))
         $('.myDiv').addClass('myBackground');
 });
 
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.myDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: cyan;
}

.myBackground {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

try this

```
$(function(){

    $(document).on('click', 'body', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).hasClass('myBackground'))
            $('.myDiv').removeClass('myBackground');
        else if ($(e.target).hasClass('myDiv'))
            $('.myDiv').addClass('myBackground');
    });

});
```